# CORS сессия сбрасывается при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: java, ajax, request, cors, jetty

Пытаюсь настроить кроссдоменный ajax запрос. В качестве сервера использую jetty. При ответе сервера добавил необходимые заголовки. Однако при обновлении страницы, сессия все равно слетает.

заголовки на стороне сервера

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8081
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length
```

вот так выглядит функция запроса

```
$.ajax( {
                url: _url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "json=" + JSON.stringify( _to_server ),
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                mimeType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            } )
                .done( function ( _from )
                {
                    _succes_func.call( null, new ExchangePacket( _from ) );
                } )
                .fail( function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
                {
                    _error_func.call( null, new Result( { state: Result.NO_SERVER_CONNECTION } ) );
                } );
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что он должен не исчезать при обновлении? Вы ведь аякс запрос отправляете и естественно в заголовках его не будет

Comment: "Он" это кто? 

Я говорю о HTTP сессии. При обновлении страницы она не должна слетать. Но вот с кроссдоменными запросами все сложнее.